# C++ How to Find Most Common Elements In a Vector

Tags: c++

Lets say that we have a vector:
[6,9,17,21,2,4,6,3,6,9,3,12,3]

how do i find the most common elements in this vector ?

in this case answer is 6 and 3,they are repeated 3 times.

this code finds the 1st most repeated one.i need others too

```
int max = 0, mostvalue = allDocumentNumbers[0];
                    for (int i = 0;i < allDocumentNumbers.size();i++)
                    {
                        int co = (int)count(allDocumentNumbers.begin(), allDocumentNumbers.end(), allDocumentNumbers[i]);
                        if (co > max)
                        {
                            max = co;
                            mostvalue = allDocumentNumbers[i];
                            cout << "Most value: " + to_string(mostvalue) << endl;

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What about a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? At least, show your efforts so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a map:

```
std::map<int, int> counters;
for(auto i: v)
{
    ++counters[i];
}
```

And then just get the maximum in this map.

Comment: how do i get the maximum in this map

Comment: i am searching this for hours still couldnt do and end up asking question.i can only find 1st most repeated element updated my question

Comment: What do you really need then? You are looking for the most common element, and ou have answers for it. That's your question.

Comment: what if there are multiple most repeated elements. thats what i couldnt solve.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple most repeated elements? You are not showing what you mean. If there are 3 '6', that's multiple values, isn't it?

Comment: 6 and 3 which are elements of the vector,they are both repeated 3 times.So most repeated elements are  6 and 3.     but my code only outputs 3

Comment: So once you have the number of max elements, just make another loop and display the numbers that have the same count.